# Localize contacts URL store wise

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, stores, multi-language

In Magento 1.9, I have 3 stores(English, Dutch, French) in 1 one website.
I am trying to localize contacts url to store wise like below.

**Magento's Default.**

English Store : *www.example.com/en/contacts*

Dutch Store : *www.example.com/nl/contacts*

French Store : *www.example.com/fr/contacts*

**What I want is language wise different url.**

English Store : *www.example.com/en/contact-information*

Dutch Store : *www.example.com/nl/contact-informatie*

French Store : *www.example.com/fr/infos-contact*

Apart from above if someone use default contacts url, it should redirect to appropriate localized url.

I tried with url rewrite, but default url still works.

Can anybody please help?